# what are the errors on this python code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have just downloaded instabot but when i tried to execute it i saw some errors, this is the main module("example.py"),there is source code :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.join(sys.path[0],'src'))

from instabot import InstaBot
from check_status import check_status
from feed_scanner import feed_scanner
from unfollow_protocol import unfollow_protocol
from follow_protocol import follow_protocol
import time


bot = InstaBot(login="username", password="password",
               like_per_day=1000,
               comments_per_day=0,
               tag_list=['follow4follow', 'f4f', 'cute'],
               tag_blacklist=['rain', 'thunderstorm'],
               user_blacklist={},
               max_like_for_one_tag=50,
               follow_per_day=300,
               follow_time=1*60,
               unfollow_per_day=300,
               unfollow_break_min=15,
               unfollow_break_max=30,
               log_mod=0,
               proxy='',
               # Use unwanted username list to block users which have username contains one of this string
               ## Doesn't have to match entirely example: mozart will be blocked because it contains *art
               ### freefollowers will be blocked because it contains free
               unwanted_username_list=['second','stuff','art','project','love','life','food','blog','free','keren','photo','graphy','indo',
                                       'travel','art','shop','store','sex','toko','jual','online','murah','jam','kaos','case','baju','fashion',
                                        'corp','tas','butik','grosir','karpet','sosis','salon','skin','care','cloth','tech','rental',
                                        'kamera','beauty','express','kredit','collection','impor','preloved','follow','follower','gain',
                                        '.id','_id','bags'])
while True:

    #print("# MODE 0 = ORIGINAL MODE BY LEVPASHA")
    #print("## MODE 1 = MODIFIED MODE BY KEMONG")
    #print("### MODE 2 = ORIGINAL MODE + UNFOLLOW WHO DON'T FOLLOW BACK")
    #print("#### MODE 3 = MODIFIED MODE : UNFOLLOW PEOPLE WHO DON'T FOLLOW BACK BASED ON RECENT FEED ONLY")
    #print("##### MODE 4 = MODIFIED MODE : FOLLOW PEOPLE BASED ON RECENT FEED ONLY")
    #print("###### MODE 5 = MODIFIED MODE : JUST UNFOLLOW EVERYBODY, EITHER YOUR FOLLOWER OR NOT")

    ################################
           ##  WARNING   ###
    ################################

    # DON'T USE MODE 5 FOR A LONG PERIOD. YOU RISK YOUR ACCOUNT FROM GETTING BANNED
    ## USE MODE 5 IN BURST MODE, USE IT TO UNFOLLOW PEOPLE AS MANY AS YOU WANT IN SHORT TIME PERIOD

    mode = 0

    #print("You choose mode : %i" %(mode))
    #print("CTRL + C to cancel this operation or wait 30 seconds to start")
    #time.sleep(30)

    if mode == 0 :
        bot.new_auto_mod()

    elif mode == 1 :
        check_status(bot)
        while bot.self_following - bot.self_follower > 200:
            unfollow_protocol(bot)
            time.sleep(10*60)
            check_status(bot)
        while bot.self_following - bot.self_follower < 400:
            while len(bot.user_info_list) <50 :
                feed_scanner(bot)
                time.sleep(5*60)
                follow_protocol(bot)
                time.sleep(10*60)
                check_status(bot)

    elif mode == 2 :
        bot.bot_mode = 1
        bot.new_auto_mod()

    elif mode == 3 :
        unfollow_protocol(bot)
        time.sleep(10*60)

    elif mode == 4 :
        feed_scanner(bot)
        time.sleep(60)
        follow_protocol(bot)
        time.sleep(10*60)

    elif mode == 5 :
        bot.bot_mode=2
        unfollow_protocol(bot)

    else :
        print ("Wrong mode!")
```

when i launched it i saw those errors :

```
Trying to login as username...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 35, in <module>
    '.id','_id','bags'])
  File "/home/mohand/Desktop/instabot.py-master/src/instabot.py", line 185, in __init__
    self.login()
  File "/home/mohand/Desktop/instabot.py-master/src/instabot.py", line 224, in login
    r = self.s.get(self.url)
  File "/home/mohand/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 501, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mohand/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/mohand/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 609, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mohand/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 423, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/home/mohand/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 594, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/home/mohand/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 350, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/home/mohand/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 835, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/home/mohand/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 330, in connect
    cert = self.sock.getpeercert()
  File "/home/mohand/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 324, in getpeercert
    'subjectAltName': get_subj_alt_name(x509)
  File "/home/mohand/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 171, in get_subj_alt_name
    ext = cert.extensions.get_extension_for_class(
AttributeError: 'Extensions' object has no attribute 'get_extension_for_class'
```

I'm using python 3.5 please i need  help :)

Comment: First issue I see is the floating parenthesis at the end of `unwanted_username_list`

Comment: @TheLazyScripter No that's correct even I thought it was a mistake. But it's an argument to function. I think the problem is in login.

Comment: Ok what should i do ?

Comment: @MYGz yep you're right, don't know how I missed that.

Comment: @MYGz ,@TheLazyScripter Can you help me ?

Comment: The issue is with `pyopenssl`. That error is thrown when a certificate fails to be authenticated. The most common issue is an old deprecated version of `cryptography`. That's where you need to start. Update your `requests` module if need be, and try to find the latest version of `cryptography`

Comment: ok thank you i will try this :)

Comment: -1 and voting to close for being a debugging question without an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This question could theoretically be useful to others with a minimal code sample and a better title (although I'm not convinced it would even then, given that the [top Google result for your error message plus 'requests' already contains the solution](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/3710)), but it clearly isn't useful in its current form.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to upgrade your version of cryptography. Check [here](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/3710) for details on this issue

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
sudo pip install cryptography --upgrade
```